# XML get multiple values from variables inside of multiple listitems with xmllint

Tags: bash, xpath, xmllint

I have some problems with xmllint --xpath. 
I do not understand how the syntax must look for the following scenario:

Following XML is given:

```
<config>
<list name="User">
  <listitem>
    <variable name="Name">admin</variable>
    <variable name="Domain">testdomain.ch</variable>
    <variable name="Account_enabled">1</variable>
    <variable name="Auth_type">0</variable>
    <variable name="PIN"></variable>
    <variable name="Rights">3</variable>
    <variable name="Authorization">kms.autodelete.deleteditems.days=30</variable>
    <variable name="Authorization">kms.autodelete.junkemail.days=30</variable>
    <variable name="Groups">gruppe</variable>
    <variable name="MailAddress">administrator</variable>
    <variable name="ForwardMode">0</variable>
    <variable name="HomeServer"></variable>
    <variable name="MailboxLocation"></variable>
    <variable name="Qstorage">0</variable>
    <variable name="Qmessage">0</variable>
    <variable name="MaxOutgoingMessageSize">0</variable>
    <variable name="DefSpamFilter">1</variable>
    <variable name="ReplyToAddress"></variable>
    <variable name="Fullname">XXX</variable>
    <variable name="Description"></variable>
    <variable name="KrbUserPrincipalName"></variable>
  </listitem>
  <listitem>
    <variable name="Name">postmaster</variable>
    <variable name="Domain">testdomain2.ch</variable>
    <variable name="Account_enabled">1</variable>
    <variable name="Auth_type">0</variable>
    <variable name="PIN"></variable>
    <variable name="Rights">0</variable>
    <variable name="Authorization">kms.webadmin</variable>
    <variable name="ForwardMode">0</variable>
    <variable name="HomeServer"></variable>
    <variable name="MailboxLocation"></variable>
    <variable name="Qstorage">0</variable>
    <variable name="Qmessage">0</variable>
    <variable name="MaxOutgoingMessageSize">0</variable>
    <variable name="DefSpamFilter">1</variable>
    <variable name="PreferredAddress"></variable>
    <variable name="ReplyToAddress"></variable>
    <variable name="Fullname"></variable>
    <variable name="Description"></variable>
    <variable name="KrbUserPrincipalName"></variable>
  </listitem>
```

I need to get the following output:

```
Name;Domain;Rights
```

In this example, the output should be:

```
admin;testdomain.ch;3
postmaster;testdomain2.ch;0
```

Thank you and best regards,
Felix

Comment: Could you please provide what you tried to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's possible with xmllint. It's easy with [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)...

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/config/list/listitem" -v "concat(variable[@name='Name'],';',variable[@name='Domain'],';',variable[@name='Rights'])" -n input.xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\> '$0 ~ /"Domain"/ || $0 ~ /"Name"/ || $0 ~ /"Rights"/ { split($2,slts,"<");if ( $0 ~ /"Rights"/ ) { printf "%s\n",slts[1] } else { printf "%s;",slts[1] } } ' filename
```

With > set as the field delimiter, we pattern match for "Domain" OR "Name" OR "Rights" then if those conditions are met, we further split the string based on < as the delimiter. This is then printed with a trailing ; in all cases apart from there "Rights" is encountered when a trailing carriage return is added.